# Show request.DATA in Django 500 error caused by Rest Framework

Tags: django, debugging, django-rest-framework

I have built an API using Django Rest Framework, but I'm facing a problem with error logging, which won't displayed the original POST data sent from the AJAX call to the API. Now I know Rest Framework uses request.DATA to parse the POST data, but I'm struggling to get this data in the Django error log, which makes it hard to debug the live application.

As an example, I send the following POST call:

```
...    
Request Payloadview source
{start:2014-07-16, end:2014-08-18}
    end: "2014-08-18"
    start: "2014-07-16"
```

And in the Django error log I get:

```
...
GET: No GET data
POST: No POST data
FILES: No FILES data
...
```

It would great if I could see in that error log which data was originally submitted via the AJAX call.
I have tried to customise the Rest Framework exception handler, but it doesn't to catch the 500 errors happening in Django.

Comment: Sentry pointed me to this issue on github which seems to do the trick: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1671, while using Sentry to log all issues.

Answer (score 5):

There is a version which works for Django 1.9+ and Rest Framework 3.4

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is None and context['request'].method not in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        context['request']._request.POST = context['request'].data

return response
```

Comment: Why the `not in permissions.SAFE_METHODS` check?

Comment: @Harel GET is "safe method", and POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE - are not. So, if you will send request with HTTP method GET, your data will be not in request body, but in URL and to access data you don't need do `context['request'].data`, because data will be in  `request.GET`.

Answer (score 4):

In settings.py :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'core.exceptions.exception_handler',
}
```

The handler:

```
def exception_handler(exc, drf_request=None):
    """
    Replace request.POST with drf_request.DATA so Sentry
    can log request properly.

    @param exc: Exception
    @param drf_request: Request
    @return: None
    """
    response = views.exception_handler(exc)
    if response is None and drf_request is not None \
            and drf_request.method not in ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']:
        request = get_request()
        request.POST = drf_request.DATA

    return response
```

Comment: This looks precisely what I was looking for! Where is `get_request()` defined, though?